# Create psycopg2 wrapper function to execute with just call function only once

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm trying to create function psycopg2 cursor execution wrapper function.

I'm tried just like this.

```
async def query_execute(query, *args):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(**db_params) # This db_params already declare before.
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query, *args)
        return cursor.fetchone()
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

This code has so many problems.

- this cursor can do only fetchone.
- connection.close maybe can not execute.

My goal is just like this.

```
result = await query_execute("SELECT * From users where id = $1 AND email = $2", ("test","test"))
result_one = result.fetchone()
```

Please tell me how to fix my code.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is my solution.

```
async def query_execute(query, *args):
    connection = await asyncpg.connect(**db_params)
    try:
        result = await connection.fetch(query, *args)
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error:{e}")
        raise
    finally:
        await connection.close()
```